# Multiple if statements printing in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm working on a simple program that asks for 3 inputs and if all 3 inputs match then a welcome message is printed. (Initials == YNH, Age == 42, DOB == 1/27/74).

Additionally, the length of the user's name (YoungNathanHeather) is printed as well as an input (color)  that prints one of three different strings.

I am having a problem where all three if statements are true and printing their strings even though the variable (color) is different when I input blue, pink, and yellow.

Maybe I am missing something huge here with nesting a bunch of if statements, but does anyone have an idea whats going on here ? I expect to input "Yellow" and see only one string print.

```
#checks if inputted information matches criteria.
#if all inputted information matches variable criteria
#(Initials == YNH, Age == 42, DOB == 1/27/74), then
#prints a Welcome message for the user.
if Initials == 'YNH':
    if Age == '42':
        if DOB == '1/27/74':
            print('Welcome Young Nathan Heather')
            print('Did you know that your name has  ' +str((len('YoungNathanHeather'))) +' letters.')
            #Asks for a color and prints a response based on if the color is pink, yellow, or blue
            color = input("If you could describe your mood in a color, what would it be ?")
            if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':
                print('According to my research Master, Blue and Yellow together  makes green. Green seems to be equal to money.')
            elif color == 'pink' or 'Pink':
                print('According to my research Master, Pink attracts women or makes a human into a women. Whatever comes first.')
            elif color == 'yellow' or "Yellow":
                print('According to my research Master, Yellow indicates a "mellow" mood. Prolong this mood if feasible.')
            else:
                print("My apologies Master. My research is shallow and I am not yet familiar with that mood's \"color\"")



        else:
            print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')
    else:
        print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')

else:
    print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')
```

Comment: `SIVABALANs-MBP:Desktop siva$ python test.py 
Welcome Young Nathan Heather
Did you know that your name has  18 letters.
If you could describe your mood in a color, what would it be ?yellow
color is :yellow
According to my research Master, Blue and Yellow together  makes green. Green seems to be equal to money.
SIVABALANs-MBP:Desktop siva$ ` what is the output that you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

When you say,

```
        if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':
```

it's interpreted as,

```
        if (color == 'blue') or ('Blue'):
```

which is true if `color == 'blue'` is true, *or* if `'Blue'` is true.  Blue is always true.  Same with the other colors

You could do something like:

```
        if color in [ 'blue', 'Blue']:
```

Which will check whether `color` exists within the list of colors.  But what about 'BlUe', 'bLuE', etc? Here's an even better solution.

```
        if color.lower() == "blue":
```

Now it matches any capitalization of blue!

Next, consider this part:

```
if Initials == 'YNH':
    if Age == '42':
        if DOB == '1/27/74':
            print('Welcome Young Nathan Heather')
            ... ... ...
        else:
            print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')
    else:
        print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')

else:
    print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')
```

That's [a lot of repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but also a lot of unnecessary indentation, and that makes the code harder to read and harder to debug.  Why not something more like:

```
if Initials == 'YNH' and  Age == '42' and DOB == '1/27/74':
    print('Welcome Young Nathan Heather')
    ... ... ...
else:
     print('Sorry, Wrong Credentials Entered')
```

Do it that way, and your code will be easier to read, and easier to write too!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, this does nothing: `if color == 'blue' or 'Blue'`, it is always True!. You must change it to `if color in ('blue', 'Blue')` or even better: `if color in {'blue', 'Blue'}`.

Why does it do nothing? Because when you write your if that way, Python checks `if color == 'blue'`, if True, executes; if False, moves on to checking `if 'Blue'`. Say your color is red, then first part of the criteria is not met, hence Python moves on to `if 'Blue'`. Now, this is always True, because according to Python:

`bool(any string except empty string)` is True, and so is `bool(any number except 0*)`! Therefore, since Boolean value of anything is True, the if condition of `if color == 'blue' or 'Blue'` is always satisfied, regardless of whatever you feed into it other than empty string or 0.

Also, you can join all of your `if`s in one line: `if Initials == 'YNH' and Age == '42' and DOB == '1/27/74'...`

*Well, to be more precise, 0 and its variants, such as 0L, 0j, 0.0, 0.00...